# upper bounds and ordered fields

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

the problem I am dealing with is N contained in R is not bounded above. the proof I have says assume the contrary and prove but I don't understand completely.

the work is as follows

there exists A z := supN in R
n<=z every n in N
n+1<=z every n in N
n<=z-1 every n in N

and somehow z-1 proves the contradiction. I don't know, help, please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So your proof assumes $\Bbb N$ is bounded above. So $z:=\sup \Bbb N$ exists (every non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$ that is bounded above has a least upper bound, the sup, a basic fact about $\Bbb R$).

Now let $n \in \Bbb N$, then $n+1 \le z$ because $n+1 \in \Bbb N$ as well and $z$ is an upperbound for $\Bbb N$ by definition.

So it follows that $n \le z-1$ by basic arithmetic facts and as $n$ was arbitrary, it turns out $z-1$ is in fact **also** an upperbound for $\Bbb N$! But $z$, being the supremum is the **smallest** upper bound for $\Bbb N$ while $z-1 < z$, a contradiction.

So the assumption that $\Bbb N$ is bounded above must be false.

Comment: You can choose whether you like this version with $z$ being the supremum better, or you can let $z$ be _any_ upper bound, and keep subtracting $1$ until, by the Archimedean property of the reals, you go below $0$ (or any other concrete natural number you like).

Comment: @Arthur this is an extended version of his proof that he didn’t understand. He didn’t mention the Archimedean property so I didn’t either. The OP might not even know this property.